# How to find best closed contour from set of points in numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, contour

I have the following image Points on the contour of chamber

[image]

To detect the shape of chamber applied `approxPolyDP` and the result is as follows.

after approxPolyDP

[image]

Is there any other method which I can use to detect the closed shape of chamber?

Comment: What do you mean by closest shape? Do you have some pre-defined set of shapes, which you want to match upon ?

Comment: I mean a closed shape. From which I can mask the points inside the contour.

Comment: A [Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)?